# Save and recall multiple Properties.Settings.Default objects?

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

To make things a tad simpler in my C# application, I decided to save all user style changes using the `Properties.Settings` properties, which works as expected.

But I liked the style change aspect of my app so much, and it is so important to the usage, that I have now decided to have savable and loadable style files(`MyStyle.xxx`) for the user to save and reload. But as I have never used these user settings before, I am unsure of how to duplicate and save this object. Can it be done simply, or can I maybe write these objects to serialized XML? What is the common approach?

P.S. I tried researching this topic but because it is so closely related to just saving user settings, all I could find was questions about saving user settings.

Comment: So user settings are most commonly used for storing the user's preferred data for their copy of your application. You create all the objects that the user will be able to save to, give them default values, and then update them when they change.

But you're thinking of using it more as a template engine or something right? So the user can choose between different styles? Am I following here?

Comment: And the user can  save the changed styles too, yes.

Comment: Consider using the Registry instead.  This is a particularly useful alternative when using Terminal Server as users access their preferences even when switching machines. File based will do the same of course if the files are networked.  I use the registry a lot, and I was delighted to find when porting to Unix/Linux under Mono, that it still worked!  I was expecting to have to re-write.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of sketchy but it has worked for me in the past and seems to be a pretty decent solution..

Firstly, create a list of settings you want and some default values.

Then create some JSON-esque format for your data and save in the setting as a string. From there you can jsut copy paste this template and make say 3 more string in your settings file for a total of 4 strings with the same JSON stuff in it.

It's a bit of a fuss parsing that info in and out but if you do set it up in JSON format then it shouldn't be too hard.